# How to compare column of two table and insert a value into new table based on comparison in stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to create a procedure which should check a column between two tables and insert a value into another table based on comparison.

**Table 1:**

```
create table table1
(
ID int not null primary key,
)
```

**Table 2:**

```
Create table table2
(
ItemID int not null primary key,
ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Orders(OrderID) ,
Descp Text
)
```

**Table 3:**

```
create table table3
(
ID int,
ItemCheck char
)
```

value of `ID` column of table 3 should be same as table1's `ID` column and 
if `ID` column of table1 table exist in table2 then  value `ItemCheck` column of table3 should be 'true' oterwise 'false'. 
Please give me some ideas and let me know if you have any doubt. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like this?

```
TRUNCATE table3;
INSERT INTO table3 (ID, ItemCheck)
  SELECT ID, 
         CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE ID = t.ID)
              THEN 'T' 
              ELSE 'F' 
         END
    FROM table1 t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @col1 varchar(10)
Declare @col2 varchar(10)

SET @col1 = Select column1 from table1 where id =1
SET @col1 = Select column1 from table1 where id =2

IF(@col1 == @col2)
BEGIN 
  //  insert statement goes here
END
```